# HTML Issue on Captive Portal

Tags: html, web

From the code below I have to create a captive portal webpage that has two buttons, one of them will have a user input his/her name, password and continue, and the other will have just a continue button which will direct the user to the redirection website automatically without the user having to input anything ( they just click on continue - "username" and "password" is already defined ). The Issue is that I need both on the same page and it is not working, On different pages it works perfectly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Company Name Hotspot - Secure Access!</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-color: #000;
}
.offer {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #F00;
 text-align: center;
}
.bolder {
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.copyright {
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
}
.button {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
body,td,th {
 color: #6FF;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>

 <title>Secure Access - Login</title>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="$PORTAL_ACTION$">
  <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
  <input name="zone" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_ZONE$">
    <center>
   <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" width="780" height="380" style="border:1px solid #000000">
     <tr height="10" bgcolor="#990000">
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000">
       <font color='white'>
        <b>
         Welcome to Bharat Telecom Hotspot
        </b></font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="mainlevel">
        <center>
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
           <td>
            <center>
             <div id="mainarea">
              <center>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                 <td>
                  <div id="maindivarea">
                   <center>
                    <div id='statusbox'>
                     <font color='red' face='arial' size='+2'>
                      <b>
                      
                      </b>
                     </font>
                    To gain access through the internet, Please enter your Username and Password or Voucher Code.<br><br>
                    If you have any difficulties you may contact our technical support technician at (Tel. No Here)<br><br>
     Kindly Note that you will be exited after 5 minutes by using the Free Wifi Access.<br><br>
     Click the Button to continue as free User.<br></div>
                    <br/>
<div id='loginbox2'>
<table>
        <tr><td><input name="auth_user" type="hidden" type="text" value="User"></td></tr>
        <br>
        <tr><td><input name="auth_pass" type="hidden" type="password" value="abc"></td></tr>
        <br>
          <td><input class="button" name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue"></td>
</table>
</div>
                    <div id='loginbox'>
      
                     <table>



                        <tr>
                          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>Free User</td>
                          </tr>
                        <tr><td align="right">Username:</td><td><input  name="auth_user" type="text" ></td></tr>
                        <tr><td align="right">Password:</td><td><input  name="auth_pass" type="password" ></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>Voucher</td></tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td align="right">Voucher Code:</td>
                          <td><input name="auth_voucher" type="text"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td><input name="accept" type="submit" class="button" value="Continue"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td align="right"></td><td></td></tr>


                     </table><br />
                                                                                    <hr />
                    
                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                                              </div>
                   </center>
                  </div>
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </table>
              </center>
             </div>
            </center>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </center>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr height="10" bgcolor="#990000">
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000">
        <p><font color='white'>
          <b>
            ©Copyright 2016 Company Hotspot. All Rights Reserved.
 </b></font><br />

     </tr>
     </table>
   </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, how do you know that which button is doing action (Submit)?
In your code there is no way to distinguish which button, as both have same name and value.

You could use same name but different value and handle code accordingly. For instance, for your second button you can use some other value like "Continue Without Password"

```
<input name="accept" type="submit" class="button" value="Continue Without Password">
```

OR, you could use two buttons with all different name like 'accept' and 'accept_1' to have two button object on a single HTML.

Comment: But in the second button there is no value.

Comment: I changed the value and also the button name but nothing changed it was still the same. I was wondering how to work around it.

Comment: Yes I did It, I changed the button names and also divided the form in two thus half was used for one button and the other half for the other. Really awesome thanks a bunch.